# Is this the only or best method for classes serializing in Java?

Tags: java, serialization

I usually use the static methods from this designed class in order to perform objects serializing of custom classes.

Even though I'm getting good results, I wonder if this is the most appropriate way for it and if there are any improvements for it?

```
public class InputOuput {        
    private static FileOutputStream         flujoSalida;
    private static ObjectOutputStream       flujoSalidaObjetos;
    private static File                     archivo;
    private static final FileChooser        seleccionador = new FileChooser();

    private static FileInputStream          flujoEntrada;
    private static ObjectInputStream        flujoEntradaObjetos;

    public static boolean serialize(Object anObject) {            
        seleccionador.setTitle("Dónde guardar el estado del programa");

        try {                
            archivo = seleccionador.showSaveDialog(null);
            if (archivo == null) return false;

            flujoSalida = new FileOutputStream(archivo);
            flujoSalidaObjetos = new ObjectOutputStream(flujoSalida);
            flujoSalidaObjetos.writeObject(anObject);
            flujoSalidaObjetos.close();
            flujoSalida.close();
        } catch (IOException error) {
            System.out.println(error.toString());
            System.out.println(error.getStackTrace());
        }            
        return true;            
    }

    public static Object deserialize() {                
        Object m=null;

        try {                
            archivo = seleccionador.showOpenDialog(null);
            if (archivo == null) return null;
            flujoEntrada = new FileInputStream(archivo);
            flujoEntradaObjetos = new ObjectInputStream(flujoEntrada);
            m= (Object) flujoEntradaObjetos.readObject();
            flujoEntradaObjetos.close();
            flujoEntrada.close();
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException error) {
            System.out.println(error.toString());
            System.out.println(error.getStackTrace());
        }            
        return m;
    }        
}
```

**I change `Object` for the custom intended class*

One good point to ask: how could I be not making the `InputOutput` class to implement `Serializable`, yet it works properly anyway?

Comment: When you have variable names like "m", you should always think of renaming.

Comment: I agree @Kinjal :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your variables should be local, except for maybe the `FileChooser`.

You swallow exceptions.  Printing a stack trace is no substitution for proper exception handling.  (By the way, logging should be done using `java.util.logging`.  If you *must* print a stack trace manually, print it to `System.err` instead of `System.out`.)  Serialization could completely fail, and the function will still return `true`.  The most appropriate behaviour should be to propagate the exception to the caller.

For greater flexibility and clarity with little additional effort, I suggest overloading `serialize()` and `deserialize()` with several variants which call each other:

```
public class InputOutput {
    private static final FileChooser seleccionador = new FileChooser();

    /**
     * Serializes an object to a file chosen by the user using a FileChooser.
     * @return true if completed, false if user cancels the FileChooser.
     */
    public static boolean serialize(Object o) throws IOException {
        seleccionador.setTitle("Dónde guardar el estado del programa");
        File f = seleccionador.showSaveDialog(null);
        if (f == null) return false;
        serialize(o, f);
        return true;
    }

    public static void serialize(Object o, File f) throws IOException {
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f)) {
            serialize(o, fos);
        }
    }

    public static void serialize(Object o, FileOutputStream fos) throws IOException {
        try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos)) {
            oos.writeObject(o);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Deserializes an object from a file chosen by the user using a FileChooser.
     * @return the deserialized object, or null if user cancels the FileChooser.
     */
    public static Object deserialize() throws IOException { ... }
    public static Object deserialize(File f) throws IOException { ... }
    public static Object deserialize(FileInputStream fis) throws IOException { ... }
}
```